# Matching consecutive digits REGEXP_REPLACE in Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to remove consecutive numbers from a string in Redshift.

From `'16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,'` I want to get `'16,3,4,16,'`.

The following construction doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,', '(.+)\1{1,}', '\1');
```

It's returning exactly the same string. :(

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try with `\\1` instead of `\1` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Was this change enough to solve your problem?

Comment: Hey Allan, thanks for your suggestion. I can't access my Redshift instance now but will try asap and let you know.

Comment: a python udf may be a good option for this, if you cannot get the above to work

Comment: Try `SELECT regexp_replace('16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,', '([0-9]+)(,\1)+', '\1')` or, as Allan has advised, double the backslashes. If neither works, the regex engine does not allow backreferences in the patterns. Well, I do not think it will work in a general case, please consider options other than regex here.

Comment: Allan and Wiktor your suggestions didn't work. I hope it's nothing to do with me running queries from SQL Workbench. Thanks for your ideas anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer using a Redshift python UDF.

```
create or replace function dedupstring(InputStr varChar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
    OutputStr=''
    PrevStr=''
    first=True
    for part in InputStr.split(','):
        if part <> PrevStr:
            if first:
                OutputStr+=part
            else:
                OutputStr+=','+part
            PrevStr=part
            first=False
    return OutputStr
$$ language plpythonu;

Select dedupstring('16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,');
```

This returns '16,3,4,16,'

Comment: Jon, I can't test this as I have no permission to run UDF, but it looks like a valid and most accurate answer so far. Thanks!

Comment: can't you get permission? see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-security-and-privileges.html

Comment: I asked the admins, hope they can give me access soon. ;)

Comment: Hey Jon, after a "few" days the admins got back to me saying they allowed me to create functions. Ran the tests, and all went beautifully! Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,', '([0-9]+,){2}', '$1') ;

 regexp_replace
----------------
 16,3,4,16,
```

Comment: not sure it works for 4 in a row or some other things - try SELECT regexp_replace('16,16,16,16,3,3,4,16,16,', '([0-9]+,){2}', '$1') ; it returns 16,16,3,16,16, (the solution using the UDF works in this and all cases)

Comment: Thanks Joe for the hint, as Jon says it doesn't work for 4 in a row, but I'll play a bit more with this idea. Thumbs up for that.

Comment: Ok ‍♂️. I answered the question as asked but, to be frank, using the database to deduplicate digits within a string is a *bad idea*. It suggests that there is a deeper data quality issue that probably needs to be addressed upstream. I can tell you from painful experience that “patching things up” in the database will hurt you eventually.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the good advice. This was a later request from our DS. We're formatting and aggregating data as an input for a process. I did what you said and rather added a subquery upstream to get the right result. Now curious about testing UDF, though. ;)