# Match only percentage values in Redshift Regex

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm having trouble with a somewhat complex regex problem in Redshift. I want to be able to extract all number values that have a percent sign following them and none of those that don't. My current script works for more simple examples but not for more complex.

I have a column that has ingredients for drinks.

> A simple example might be `"95% Apple, 5% Grape"` or `50.25% grape, 49.75% apple`. I'm able to parse this with 
>   `'[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?%)?'`. However, more complex examples like `"50% Apple, 50% Grape, 2mg grape juice"` or `"100% Juice,50% Apple, 50% Grape"` result in me extracting `"2" and 100, 50, and 50,` respectively.

`[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?%)?`

> I have been able to grab every digit, but I only want to grab digits with a percentage sign immediately following it where the value "100%" is not with other percent values. So using this example `"100% Juice,50% Apple, 50% Grape"`, I only want the two 50% values. Edit: I also want to clarify that I'm using the regexp_substr function, so the two 50% values would be in their own columns by using the index.

Comment: Your regex example implies that some of the percentages you are looking for are like 50.25%. If that is true, then you should include something like that in your test examples above. Also it sounds like you do not want to capture any percentages >= 100% (including hyperbole like 150% or 150.25%), is that right?

Comment: Regarding >100%, yes, that is correct. I will add a test example above to indicate that.

Comment: @WalterWhalen this can be done with a python UDF, have you looked at this option? Are you able to create and use these (you need to get access) . see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084967/matching-consecutive-digits-regexp-replace-in-redshift/54088629#54088629 as an example. Let me know if this is an option for you and I may be able to help with an answer.

Comment: did you solve this? if so please post answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below

`\b\d?\d%\s`
https://regex101.com/r/wxGfaX/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using a python udf

```
create or replace function process_percentages(InputStr varChar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
    import re
    OutputStr = ''
    pattern=re.compile('(\d+(\.\d+)?%)')
    if ('100%' in InputStr) & (InputStr.count('%') == 1):
        OutputStr='100%,'
    else:
        for m in re.finditer(pattern, InputStr):
            if float(m.group(1)[:-1]) < 100.0:
                OutputStr+=m.group(1) + ','
    return OutputStr[:-1]
$$ language plpythonu;
```

then you can use it like:

```
Select process_percentages('10% Apple, 10% 5% Grape');
Select process_percentages('100% 10% Apple, 10% 5% Grape');
Select process_percentages('123% nothing 10% Apple, 10% Grape');
Select process_percentages('100% Apple, Grape');
Select process_percentages('10.56% Apple, 5.22% Grape');
```

This is always going to work and is easily tailorable if your needs become a bit more complex.

You do need to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-security-and-privileges.html first to get permissions